# Count matching values between dictionary and dataframe considering keys / column order in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, similarity

I want to match a specific data entry (dictonary/dataframe with 20 variables) with a possible same entry of a database.

As there is no unique identifier and for some entries a lot of missing values I wanted to make a "naive" guess. Means I want to count all matching values row-wise and take the top 10 prospects.

Currently, I transform the dictionary to a list and use `.isin()` to get the number of matching values.

```
db['no_matches'] = db.isin(list_of_criterias).sum(1)
prospects = db.nlargest(10 ['no_matches'])
```

However, my approach is misleading, as I count matches regardless of the column order/name.

Means, if my search value is e.g. `column1 = 'foo'`, it also matches with `'foo'` values in my database that are not located in `column1`.

Is there a way to count matching values row-wise and considering column order at the same time?

Thanks.

***Update:***

Thanks to the comment by [Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) I passed the corresponding dictionary to the `.isin()` function. However, I receive an `type error`.

```
In[9]: type(clean_criteria)
Out[9]: dict

db.isin(clean_criteria) #Throws Error

TypeError: only list-like or dict-like objects are allowed to be passed to DataFrame.isin(), you passed a 'str'
```

Comment: You could pass a dictionary to `isin`, which will match your columns with the dict's keys.

Comment: @QuangHoang Hi thanks for the hint, however I receive a type error although I checked the data type of my dictionary beforehand.

Comment: `isin` takes array argument, get your dict's keys place in list and use it inside your `isin` method

Comment: Thanks @Joe, I used `dict_criteria = df_criteria.to_dict('list')` and it worked fine.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposed/derived solution by comments (for community wiki):

```
dict_criteria = df_criteria.to_dict('list') 

db['no_matches'] = db.isin(dict_criteria).sum(1)  
prospects = db.nlargest(10 ['no_matches'])
```

**Explanation**

- .to_dict('list') -- 'list' argument transforms dict values from skalar to list/array object
- .isin() -- passing a 'list' is matching any value not considering order while passing a dictionary does